# Infix relation transformer syntax in Isabelle

Tags: syntax, isabelle

Given

```
notation
  rtranclp  ("(_^**)" [1000] 1000)
```

I can write, given an infix op `⇒`

```
"op ⇒⇧*⇧* x x'"
```

but not the much more readable and prettier

```
"x ⇒⇧*⇧* x'"
```

I know that for every concrete relation (`⇒` in this case), I can set up an abbreviation for this. But can I also solve this generally, i.e. for any infix relation?

If yes, can I extend that to multiple relations and other arguments? For example, given two infix relations `⇒` and `▹`, and another term `y` I want to set it up so that I can write

```
x (⇒;▹)⇗y⇖ x'
```

(note the infix use) instead of

```
foo op ⇒ op ▹ y x x'
```

(where, in my case, has type `foo :: ('a ⇒ 'a ⇒ bool) ⇒ ('a ⇒ 'b ⇒ bool) ⇒ 'b ⇒ 'a ⇒ 'a`).

Comment: I keep coming back to that same question myself, but never gave it serious thought. Maybe I should. Btw: Your last two examples are somewhat confusing to me (what is `foo` and why is `y` used twice?). Could you elaborate?

Comment: I elaborated the example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that a general solution for all infix relations is not possible, because the parser does not know about the relation symbols in isolation. As can be seen from the implementation in [mixfix.ML](http://isabelle.in.tum.de/repos/isabelle/file/8f4a332500e4/src/Pure/Syntax/mixfix.ML#l124), an infix declaration with relation symbol `<` is equivalent to two mixfix declarations, namely `"op <"` and `"(_ < _)"` with appropriate precedences.

However, there is a more generic and elegant solution than to introduce abbreviations for all combinations of predicates and predicate transformers. First, introduce a syntactic category for relational symbols. To also get the right output, add a syntactic marker `_infix`

```
nonterminal rel
syntax (output) "_infix" :: "rel ⇒ logic" ("_")
```

Then, declare a syntax constant `_rtranclp_rel` for infix use with infix relations.

```
syntax "_rtranclp_rel" :: "logic ⇒ rel ⇒ logic ⇒ logic" ("(_ _⇧*⇧* _)")
translations "_rtranclp_rel x R y" ⇀ "CONST rtranclp R x y"
translations "_rtranclp_rel x (_infix R) y" ↽ "CONST rtranclp R x y"
```

Now, add a syntax translation to your relation `rel` that you want to use with `_rtranclp_rel`:

```
consts rel :: "nat ⇒ nat ⇒ bool" (infix "⇒" 100)

syntax "_rel_infix" :: rel ("⇒")
translations "_rel_infix" ⇀ "CONST rel"
translations "_rel_infix" ↽ "_infix (CONST rel)"
```

Then, Isabelle should be able to correctly parse and pretty-print `x ⇒⇧*⇧* z`. Note, however, that all fully applied instances of `rtranclp` are pretty-printed infix (e.g., `rtranclp R x y`, independent of whether the relation is an infix symbol.

This mechanism then also works for your function `foo`:

```
consts foo :: "('a ⇒ 'a ⇒ bool) ⇒ ('b ⇒ 'b ⇒ bool) ⇒ 'b ⇒ 'a ⇒ 'a ⇒ bool"

syntax "_foo_rel" :: "logic ⇒ rel ⇒ rel ⇒ logic ⇒ logic ⇒ logic" ("_ '(_;_')⇗_⇖ _")
translations "_foo_rel x R S y z" ⇀ "CONST foo R S x y z"
translations "_foo_rel x (_infix R) (_infix S) y z" ↽ "CONST foo R S x y z"
```

Of course, the precedences in the mixfix annotations should be adjusted to sensible ones. It is even possible to do this recursively. For example:

```
syntax "_rtranclp_rel2" :: "rel ⇒ rel" ("_⇧*⇧*")
translations "_rtranclp_rel2 R" ⇀ "CONST rtranclp R"
translations "_rtranclp_rel2 (_infix R)" ↽ "_infix (CONST rtranclp R)"

term "x (⇒⇧*⇧*;⇒)⇗y⇖ z"
```

Comment: Probably no one has ever worked that out properly (I guess that my suggestion above is not the best solution to the problem). If you think that this should be supported by default, you can post on the developer mailing list and see whether others find it as useful. Then, there's a chance to get it into Pure (infix is defined in Pure, so HOL is too late).